# AngularJs, replace text pattern with DOM-object

Tags: angularjs

```
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>

<script>

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.actionme = function(){

  var z = document.getElementById("txt_select");
  z.innerHTML = "Apple is <b>%%red|green|not an orange%%</b>";  };

   $scope.copyme = function(){
      document.getElementById("txt_output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt_select").innerHTML;
   }

}
</script>
</head>
<body > 
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">     
    <div id="txt_select" contenteditable="true"> initial text </div>
    <br>
    <div id="txt_output"> initial text </div>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="actionme()">generate</button> 
    <button ng-click="copyme()">copy</button>  
  </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Content of div'txt_select' need to be generated by some "document template string": Apple is %%red|green|not an orange%%.

User have to see in place of %%red|green|not an orange%% combobox with this three options in dropdownlist. And as result in 'txt_output' there need to be simple text with user selected item: "Apple is not an orange".

How i can do textreplace-magic with angular? Generated combobox must be able to can use all (or most) angular features.

//yes, i'm noob)

//edit reason: replaced `<textarea>` with `<div contenteditable="true">`

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: first you don't declare a controller so this will be a problem. second you should use ng-model in the textarea to  bind the value of the textarea with a variable in the scope

Comment: if i only know what i can and should do then i will just write code and not bother anyone))

Answer (score 0):

Since there are more than two options I would suggest you to set it in the controller. But if you want to do a replace in the html itself, then 
you can use the following if it is in "if else" format:

```
{{ ifOrangeOrNot ? Orange : Green }}
```

Let the default text be "This is not an orange".

Hope this helps.

Comment: i think your answer if totaly wrong. ng-class add a class according to a bool expression, he want to put text inside the text-area. use ng-model for this

Comment: i don't want simple text manipulation. I need create objects and somehow bind them to angular.

Answer (score 0):

- first you don't declare a controller so this will be a problem.
- second you should use ng-model in the textarea to bind the value of
  the textarea with a variable in the scope

a little example her http://plnkr.co/edit/Zea3zZqaagDdO4s8pZRC?p=preview

in the html:

```
     <textarea ng-model="text"></textarea>
```

in the controller :

```
     $scope.text = 'param01 : value01\nparam02 : value02\nparam03 : value03\nparam04 : value04\nparam05 : value05\nparam06 : value06\n';
```

Comment: Well, i discovered that textbox even not able use <b>,<i>. So combobox insertion also impossible. Edited question with `contenteditable=true`